# Cloud storage api suggestion for often video uploads

Tags: google-drive-api, dropbox-api, onedrive, cloud-storage

We are starting a software business. It includes :
-Often video file uploads to the cloud storage 
-After upload is done, the software will send the video URL to the specified email adress.

We use just storage in cloud, the processing will be done locally. For this system, what is your cloud service suggestion in terms of performance, api richness, api easiness etc.? SkyDrive, Dropbox, Google Drive or another? (The first business is done in Australia, then in Turkey)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my own experience, Google Drive is a better solution as far as I can say.

- Fully rich REST API.
- A dozen of client libraries for each language.
- Open with your application support from Google Drive UI: https://developers.google.com/drive/integrate-open
- Dozens of samples for each client library and language.
- Great community support and responsive Googlers.
- Google brand is internationally more welcomed, therefore Google sign is more trusted.